# bootstrap typeahead directive not working on input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-typeahead

```
    var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {


    $scope.FDLAccountOther = [{
      "fdlAccountId": 300,
      "fdlAccountName": "IS00698000",
      "fdlAccountDesc": "PT Rebates -To Trading Desks on selling concessions paid to IFG",
      "fdlAccountType": "R",
      "setId": "FDL01",
      "isDefault": null,
      "balanceForward": null,
      "bsIndicator": null,
      "status": "Active"
    }, {
      "fdlAccountId": 301,
      "fdlAccountName": "IS00699000",
      "fdlAccountDesc": "PT Rebates -To Trading Desks on selling concessions paid to IIG",
      "fdlAccountType": "R",
      "setId": "FDL01",
      "isDefault": null,
      "balanceForward": null,
      "bsIndicator": null,
      "status": "Active"
    }]
    });
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.2.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="plunker">         
    <div class="input-group" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <input type="text" 
             class="form-control"
             ng-model="formData_TransGrid.fdlAcctNameOther"
             placeholder="Enter FDL Account" 
             uib-typeahead="item.fdlAccountName as item.fdlAccountName for item in FDLAccountOther | filter:$viewValue|limitTo:3" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-success ebtn"
                type="button"
                data-toggle="modal" 
                data-target="#FDLAccountLookUp">
          Find FDL 
        </button>
      </span>
    </div>
    </html>
```

in actual there are lot of more records, but the typeahead suggestions does not seem to be working, any help?

### Update

adding uib in front of typeahead directive has solved the issue. thanks for the help

### Update

adding uib in front of typeahead directive has solved the issue. thanks for the help

Comment: The typeahead work in the current snippet, is this is what you need, nothing was wrong with your code. Maybe you forgot to add reference to  'ui.bootstrap' in the module creation. I have change `typeahead` to `uib-typeahead`, that could have done the trick.

Comment: yea adding uib seems to have done the trick. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your typeahead logic was all working, but you needed to update a few things in your script template to get it to work:

- just as you updated `typeahead` to `uib-typeahead`, you needed to update `typeaheadHighlight:query` to `uibTypeaheadHighlight:query`
- you need to use the `ng-bind-html` attribute rather than `bind-html-unsafe`
- the script has no knowledge of the `item` from your typeahead config, so you need to use `match.model`

Which results in the following...

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/tpl.html">
    <a><div>
        <span style="display:block;" class="registration" ng-bind-html="match.model.fdlAccountName | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
        <span ng-bind-html="match.model.fdlAccountDesc | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query"></span> &middot;
        <span ng-bind-html="match.model.status | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
    </div></a>
</script>
```

Here's the full snippet:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {


    $scope.FDLAccountOther = [{
      "fdlAccountId": 300,
      "fdlAccountName": "IS00698000",
      "fdlAccountDesc": "PT Rebates -To Trading Desks on selling concessions paid to IFG",
      "fdlAccountType": "R",
      "setId": "FDL01",
      "isDefault": null,
      "balanceForward": null,
      "bsIndicator": null,
      "status": "Active"
    }, {
      "fdlAccountId": 301,
      "fdlAccountName": "IS00699000",
      "fdlAccountDesc": "PT Rebates -To Trading Desks on selling concessions paid to IIG",
      "fdlAccountType": "R",
      "setId": "FDL01",
      "isDefault": null,
      "balanceForward": null,
      "bsIndicator": null,
      "status": "Active"
    }]
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
 <head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@1.1.1" data-semver="1.1.1" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-1.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.2.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
       <script type="text/ng-template" id="/tpl.html">
            <a><div>
                <span style="display:block;" class="registration" ng-bind-html="match.model.fdlAccountName | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
                <span ng-bind-html="match.model.fdlAccountDesc | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query"></span> &middot;
                <span ng-bind-html="match.model.status | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
            </div></a>
        </script>

</head>
     
    <div class="input-group" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <input type="text" 
             class="form-control"
             ng-model="formData_TransGrid.fdlAcctNameOther"
             placeholder="Enter FDL Account" 
             uib-typeahead="item.fdlAccountName as item.fdlAccountName for item in FDLAccountOther | filter:$viewValue|limitTo:3"  
             typeahead-template-url="/tpl.html" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-success ebtn"
                type="button"
                data-toggle="modal" 
                data-target="#FDLAccountLookUp">
          Find FDL 
        </button>
      </span>
    </div>
    </html>
```